# Single-window in terminal without full desktop environment?

Tags: graphics, xorg, 17.10, window, wayland

Ok, so this sounds insane, but say I install Ubuntu Server on my computer, and I'm contempt with using the console for most things. However, I still want to be able to play Steam games, or maybe use Google Chrome or an IDE or that kind of thing. Is it possible to have a single window in the console?

I'm willing to bet such a thing doesn't exist, but is it even possible? Just to be clear, I'm not talking about just running `startx` and creating a desktop whenever I need one, I mean running my window in the console without needing to switch to another TTY. Also, Wayland is acceptable (In fact, I'd honestly prefer Wayland, but X works too)

One more thing, graphics acceleration/OpenGL is a requirement (Obviously, since I said I'd like to be able to play games)

And before somebody else says this, I know, this is pretty much completely pointless. I have a lot of time to waste, let's just leave it at that :D

EDIT:
I have tried `startx chromium-browser --kiosk --`, but this just hangs and when I `CTRL-C` it logs me out of Wayland in my other TTY (I am doing my testing on Ubuntu 17.10 Desktop, it may work better in Server, I'm not sure). I'm also not sure that this would enable graphics acceleration

Comment: It's possible. I once had spawned X server just to run Virtual Box only. Been ages ago, so don't recall how I did that, but it's 100% possible

Comment: Thank you! I'll probably go off and do my own research now, and then return to this thread

Comment: I have tried `startx chromium-browser --kiosk --` which I found on some blog site, but the command just hangs and doesn't do anything on my system. I'm guessing this has to do with 17.10, so I'll add that tag to this question